# Xamarin Forms Bind Image from Resources/Drawable folder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. What I am trying to do is bind an ImageSource from a ViewModel. The image file name is called ledstrip.png and is located in the Resources/Drawable folder. I am using the following xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="70" Margin="20,20,20,0">
                    <StackLayout Opacity="0.3" BackgroundColor="White"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Source="{Binding DeviceImage}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />

                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in my ViewModel I have the following code:

```
public class VM_DeviceList : BindableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<DisplayedDevice> _knownDeviceList;
    public ObservableCollection<DisplayedDevice> knownDeviceList
    {
        get
        {
            return _knownDeviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_knownDeviceList != value)
            {
                _knownDeviceList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public VM_DeviceList()
    {
        knownDeviceList = new ObservableCollection<DisplayedDevice>();
        MyHandler();
    }

    private async Task LoadKnownDeviceList()
    {
        foreach (KnownDevice device in App.KnownDeviceList)
        {
            DisplayedDevice displayedDevice = new DisplayedDevice();

            displayedDevice.Id = device.Id;
            displayedDevice.Name = device.Name;

            switch (device.Type)
            {
                case "ledstrip":
                    displayedDevice.DeviceImage = "ledstrip.png";
                    break;
                case "triangle":
                    displayedDevice.DeviceImage = "triangle.png";
                    break;
            }

            knownDeviceList.Add(displayedDevice);
        }
    }

    public Task MyHandler()
    {
        return LoadKnownDeviceList();
    }

    public class DisplayedDevice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DeviceImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I type "ledstrip.png" in the xaml ImageSource, the image gets displayed, but when I bind it like the way I show above, no image appears on the screen!

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried writing `"ledstrip.png"`?

Comment: Yes, but that results in the same situation..... No image displayed

Comment: what is "displayedDevice" in this situation?

Comment: displayedDevice is a class that will be put in a list at the end!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Did you set to "ledstrip.png" to Content

Comment: try setting Build action for the image "ledstrip.png" to content.

Comment: Done that, but again.... Still nothing shows up

Comment: After changing the build action. you need to build the project

Comment: Shouldn't it be "{Binding NameOfTheClassInstance.DeviceImage}" ? i don't know if you are setting the binding inside a list or not

Comment: @AvinashReddy I rebuilded the whole probject but no Image yet. The Image is inside a ListView, so I add the Class to a List and at the top of the ListView I set the source to the List, so it should be working fine

Comment: Also, try to just bind the string, you don't need to create an ImageSource to bind in the source, it accepts strings and it will get you the Drawable Image for you

Comment: Strings also don't work in my case. If I add "ledstrip" directly in the source of the xaml it works, but when I give the DeviceImage the value "ledstrip" it gives me nothing

Comment: Just for the sake of removing the binding from the equation, what happens if you directly put "ledstrip"?

Comment: The image gets displayed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209704/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-a-vreeswijk).

Comment: Add `OnPropertyChanged` to `DisplayedDevice `. It should work. Can you check this

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on `DisplayedDevice` and call the `NotifyPropertyChanged ` on setter of `DeviceImage`.

Comment: Can you only tell me what I need to do with setter?

Comment: I have added it has an answer could you please check and tell if it works??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are altering the DisplayImage on a separate for loop. You have to Notify the UI that the `DisplayImage` property value has been changed.

Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for notifying that `DisplayImage` property of `DisplayedDevice` class has been changed to the UI.

```cs
public class DisplayedDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string deviceImage;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DeviceImage
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceImage;
        }

        set
        {
            deviceImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, but 1 question! Should I set the BuildAction of the ledstrip.png to Content or Embedded Resource?

Comment: Should be `Android Resource` for android and `BundleResource` for iOS. Where are the images?

Comment: In the android/resources/drawable folder